# Call specific method in Class based api view django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i am new to DRF, and implemneting class based views and a sample example is this i have tried

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
class ProductList(APIView):
    print "inside"

    def get_user_products(self, request, user_id, format=None):
        products = Product.objects.all(user_id=user_id)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_seller_products(self, request, seller_id, format=None):
        products = Product.objects.filter(seller_id=seller_id)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, user_id, seller_id, format=None):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.DATA, context={'request':request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.object.user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            serializer.object.seller = Seller.objects.get(id=seller_id)
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i this class for my product apis , but i am not sure how can i access individual methods to access the corresponding result, like how can i hit get_user_products or get_seller_products

Right now when i call this api like this http://localhost:8000/products

as GET method this class executed and it prints "inside" as you can see, but how do i call the methods inside it

Here is the url.py for this app

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^login$', 'userapp.views.login_user', name="login"),
    url(r'^products$', 'productapp.views.ProductList', name="product-list"),
]
```

Comment: It looks like you may be using a very old version of DRF (`request.DATA` hasn't existed for a while), I'd highly recommend upgrading and switching that to `request.data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to use the `api_view` decorator to decorate class-based views; you use `api_view` with function-based views.

If you want to use a class-based view, like the one in your example, remove the `print` statement, and the `api_view` decorator, and include the view in your urlconf by importing the view, and using `ProductList.as_view()`, as shown in [the tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/). In your case, the urlconf might look like this:

```
from productapp.views import ProductList

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^login$', 'userapp.views.login_user', name="login"),
    url(r'^products$', ProductList.as_view(), name="product-list"),
]
```

Also, keep in mind, that using strings containing import paths for your views in urlpatterns is deprecated, and support for this will be removed in an upcoming version of Django. Instead, import all your views inside your urlconf, and use the view functions directly, for example:

```
from productapp.views import ProductList
from userapp.views import login_user

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^login$', login_user, name="login"),
    url(r'^products$', ProductList.as_view(), name="product-list"),
]
```

Comment: done the changes, but now it is throwing GET is not allowed , and also can you explain how would i access the the various functions inside the class and what will be apis for that ?

Comment: Well, GET is not supported by your view, because you didn't implement the `get` method in that class. As for your other question, I would recommend doing a Python language tutorial.

Comment: I am trying to dispatch the request to a method, how do I provide the proper request instead of HttpRequst (WsgiRequest)

Comment: Please, ask a new question, Akshay. This is not related to my answer in any way.